# Mocha with db-migrate fails to complete tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, es6-promise, dbmigrate

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to properly test this bit of code:

```
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const restify = require('restify')
const errs = require('restify-errors')

const expect = chai.expect
chai.use(chaiHttp)

const willerror = true

const server = restify.createServer()
server.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  if (!willerror) res.send()
  next(willerror ? new errs.InternalServerError() : null)
})

describe('Server test', function () {
  before(async function () {
    const c = {config: {dev: {driver: 'sqlite3', filename: ':memory:'}}}
    const dbm = require('db-migrate').getInstance(true, c)
    dbm.silence(true)
    await dbm.reset().then(() => dbm.up('all', 'all'))
  })
  after(function (done) {
    server.close(done)
  })
  it('posts', function (done) {
    const client = chai.request(server)
    client.get('/')
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(err).to.be.null
        expect(res).to.have.status(200)
        done()
      })
  })
})
```

(Note: it requires at least one migration, but it can be empty: `db-migrate create one` should suffice).

The output I get:

[image]

Removing the contents of the `before()` call (leaving just `before(async function(){})`) gives what what I'd expect:

[image]

Why aren't these tests finishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [db-migrate registers an `uncaughtException` handler](https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate/blob/d5a688e2724f247ea7a24cd46305136ab693e920/lib/commands/helper/register-events.js#L6-L9).

To defeat it, add `throwUncatched: true` to the configuration object passed to `db-migrate`.  In my case:

```
const c = {throwUncatched: true, config: {dev: {driver: 'sqlite3', filename: ':memory:'}}}
```